# Can't run ionic 3 build because of this strange issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

When I type `ionic cordova build android --prod`
It throws unexpected pipe FilterPipe in "..components/search/filter.pipe" imported by app.module . Please add a ngmodule anotation to fix it.

I've implemented this pipe in App Module as well:

```
import { FilterPipe } from '../components/search/filter.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    NgxEmojiPickerModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    FilterPipe
  ],
```

What is wrong? How can we overcome issue and generate android apk for testing on real devise?

Comment: Pipes don't go in `imports`, they go in `declarations`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add **`FilterPipe`** to **`imports`** array of **`AppModule`** because **`FilterPipe`** is not a module. Add it to **`declarations`** array.

```
import { FilterPipe } from '../components/search/filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      MyApp,
      FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [...],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying I did it but it says can't determine a module for class filter pipe

Comment: I added in app module it shows the same. Removed and added in components module again the same. It looks impossible to create a apk.

Comment: Are you using separate module for pipes or did you declare your FilterPipe some where else in your application ?